# Linked Server - Can see tables but not columns

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I am trying to query a linked server, when I expand object explorer in SSMS, I can see all db's on the server and all tables within the respective db's but cannot expand to see the columns. I also cannot run any queries with the following errors:

1 - If I right click on the table name and click script table as - select to - new query window, I get the following error

> [LinkedServerName].[singhm]..[testtable]  contains no columns that can be selected or the current user does not have permissions on that object.

2 - If I run the an openquery statement as follows:

```
select * 
from openquery(LinkedServerName ,'select * from [singhm]..[testtable]')
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "MSDASQL"
>   for linked server "LinkedServerName".

For context purposes, My linked server is an ODBC connection to a MySQL db datasource.

I would be grateful for any advice and/or direction regarding this matter.

Many thanks,
Manpaal Singh

Comment: So, you're trying to use MSDASQL to create a linked server connection **to** a MySQL database?

Comment: @Brian - When adding the linked server, following/referring to multiple online tutorials, I didn't point the server to any particular provider but all tutorials do refer to configuring MSDASQL which I did. I have created an ODBC adapter and connecting to a ODBC dsn which connects to the MySQL datasource. It connects fine in excel and I can get data from ODBC in excel so the connection is working for that. When trying to do the same thing in SSMS, the connection is established i.e. If I test the connection, it works, I can see all the db's and tables but cannot expand to see the columns.

Comment: ohh, that's right - MSDASQL is the "OLE DB provider for ODBC drivers".  Sorry - it's been a while.  I'm afraid I don't have anything else here.

Comment: Is there anyone who could help with this, still struggling to make this work and unable to find anything online??

Comment: Two questions:  1 - Did you really name your linked server `LinkedServerName'? 2 - How have you validated the ODBC connection?

Comment: @Brian . No no, the linked server is called MySQL. Apologies, I should've amended my question with the correct name. 2) I'm able to 'Get Data' from ODBC both in Excel and Power BI, and subsequently run reports and/or run aggregations. I'm just unable to query the db's in SSMS.

Comment: Then I got nothin'.  Sorry.

Comment: @Brian Thank you for your efforts. If I find a solution, i'll be sure to post it in this thread.

Comment: @Brian So it turns out, I needed to install a different odbc provider. https://download.cnet.com/ODBC-NET-Data-Provider/3000-2206_4-10731463.html . I can now query the linked server using the following syntax. select top 10 * from openquery(MYSQL,'select * from singhm.testtable' ) .

Comment: Write that up as an Answer and accept it - that way others who encounter this issue and search here for a solution will find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to [download](https://download.cnet.com/ODBC-NET-Data-Provider/3000-2206_4-10731463.html) and install a different odbc provider. I can now query the linked server using the following syntax.

```
select top 10 * from openquery(MYSQL,'select * from singhm.testtable')
```

Comment: Ok - but can you now see the columns - have same issue.